# Netbeans Persistence Unit Removal

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence

I created a Persistence Unit in Netbeans and have since deleted the Persistence.xml file. Now whenever I run my project, I get tonnes of errors like "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Hi__Score_OldPU". How can I get rid of my Persistence Unit entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error happen when persistence.xml is at the wrong place (Project-->WebContent-->META-INF-->persistence.xml).

It should be here (src-->META-INF-->persistence.xml)

If that folder doesn't exist you can create a folder "META-INF" at src and put persistence.xml on it.

here my persistence.xml look like this.

> `
>   
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="livraria" transaction-type ="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
    <class>br.com.k19.modelo.Editora</class>  
    <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>  

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>  
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/K21_livraria_bd"/>  
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>  
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>  

    </properties>  
</persistence-unit>
```

`